# Wrong reference for fill and comb options

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I'm trying to draw a sine in xy plan, fill it with some color, and draw some arrows (dirac) to show it can be considered as a vector. I tried this but the reference of the arrows is 0 and not the x axis and the triangle marker does not rotation depending the sign of y. The fill option is not working either.

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},
 >=stealth, 
 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,
 axis/.style={thick,->},
 wave/.style={thick,color=#1,smooth}
]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[axis] (O) -- +(12,0,0) node [right] {x};
\draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,2,0) node [right] {y};
\draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,0,2) node [above] {z};

\draw[wave=blue, variable=\x,samples at={0,0.25,...,10}]
plot (\x,{sin(2*\x r)},0)node[anchor=north]{$\vec{E}$};

\draw[ycomb,mark=triangle,variable=\x,samples at={0,0.25,...,10}] plot (\x,        {sin(2*\x r)},0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result :
[image: Dirac problem]
[image: Fill problem]

So several problems but I believe you will help me out.

Thanks !

PS : I've also tried in scope env. but that's not better...

Comment: Not sure about what you want to fix. Do you want the arrow tips to follow the line? What else?

Comment: Draw the Diracs in the good plan with x axis reference, with a good orientation of the triangle markers and fix the fill problem. Both problems are connected I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the vectors with the following code:

```
\foreach \x in {0,0.25,...,10}
   \draw[->] (\x,0,0) -- (\x,{sin(2*\x r)},0);
```

If you want, you can change the arrow tips and use any of those defined by `tikz` (see the chapter "Arrow Tip Library" of the manual).

The full code and the output:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
%\usepackage[french]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)},
 >=stealth, 
 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,
 axis/.style={thick,->},
 wave/.style={thick,color=#1,smooth}
]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[axis] (O) -- +(12,0,0) node [right] {x};
\draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,2,0) node [right] {y};
\draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,0,2) node [above] {z};

\draw[wave=blue, variable=\x,samples at={0,0.25,...,10}]
plot (\x,{sin(2*\x r)},0)node[anchor=north]{$\vec{E}$};

\foreach \x in {0,0.25,...,10}
  \draw[->] (\x,0,0) -- (\x,{sin(2*\x r)},0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Wow !!! Awesome !!! That's elegant and quite obvious... now... Any idea for the fill problem ?

Comment: I don't know a proper solution. Looking at you output it seems that the area filled is between the curve and the segment that connects the initial ad final points. You could get a "correct" filling if both points fall on the x axis, by choosing the final x value as multiple of half the wavelength.

Comment: Thanks LucaD ! It woks well anyway by setting a multiple of pi and by decreasing the sampling !